# Toasting bread in a gas oven

Tags: bread, oven

I am trying to toast bread in a gas oven on a rack about 8 inches from bottom, but all the toast in the centre part of the rack are burnt and the ones to the sides are perfect, is this a normal thing with gas ovens or is my oven faulty? The bottom cover is in place I have not adjusted anything, I use a temperature setting of 180 degrees Celsius. Please do not chastise me for trying this I am just experimenting to see if I can Economize on equipment and even energy as most of the times something else will be going in the oven.

I suspect that it is because of where the flame is at the bottom and that I could place a thick metal plate on the centre of the oven floor, to prevent this, but I prefer to hear from someone with experience or any other expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do that frequently. Hot spots develop in our oven too, but we control the thing by just swapping the bread from center to edges twice along the process.

I think adding a "thick metal plate" would do too, but the toasting time will increase (or at least the time needed to pre-heat the oven will be greater).

HTH!